# I cannot do https redirection on my website on .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, https, security-certificate

Am having a local classified website. I bought SSL for the domain but cannot put https redirect on htaccess since my developer wrote somerule on htaccess to get url for SEO. Can some help for the same... Find the Screenshot of the rewrite vode below.

[image: Htaccess Error]

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of your htaccess file instead of just a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

> ...but cannot put https redirect on htaccess since my developer wrote somerule on htaccess to get url for SEO.

That's not a reason that would prevent you from doing "https redirection" in `.htaccess`. Just make sure you put the redirection at the **top of your file**, before the existing rules.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]
```

---

HOWEVER, your site does not appear to be "HTTPS-ready" yet. Requesting the HTTPS version of your site directly does not result in a functioning website. You need to get your "developer" to *fix it*. For example, you have numerous hardcoded URL-paths to the HTTP version in the HTML, including the `base` and `rel="canonical"` tags, this is going to result in the static resources (CSS, JS, etc.) from failing to load with mixed-content warnings.

Comment: Let me check with my developer about the http path,,, thanks alot